# Не проигрывается анимация Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, анимация

заранее извиняюсь за наверное тупой вопрос,просто только недавно начал изучать данный инструмент.Сделал анимацию в самом Unity,но почему то она не проигрывается,Вот скрин компонента "Animation" на данном обьекте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вы уверены, что анимация создана именно для того объекта, на котором висит компонент animation

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял,то да.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, окно анимации с этой анимацией

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3xPPLrw

Comment: При создании новой анимации создается два новых файла: анимация и аниматор. Может быть вам лучше попробовать повесить на объект не анимацию, а компонент аниматор? Просто перетащить вашу анимацию из папки игры на список компонентов объекта или нажать добавить компонент, найти Animator, после чего указать в компоненте Animator в качестве анимации вашу

Comment: В компоненте Animator можно указать только контроллер анимации

Comment: Я сейчас у себе проверю и вам напишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая идея, должна сработать:

1. Нажимаете на вашу анимацию в папке игры.
2. Сверху инспектора жмете на 3 вертикальных точки (в столбик)
3. Меняете Normal на Debug
4. Ставите галочку в Legacy
5. Меняете назад Debug на Normal
6. Анимация прикреплена к объекту и пробуйте

Comment: Вопрос к 5 пункту,назад надо поменять наверно на Normal,просто не вижу в том окошке Legacy

Comment: Да-да, ошибся, подредактирую

Comment: Ну у меня на Legacy галочка вроде и до этого стояла,не помогает(

Comment: Кстати,я вот кое что заметил,она проигрываеться,но 1 раз

Comment: Ну так б и писали))). Тогда нужно просто поменять wrap mode у анимации с default или once на что-то другое

Comment: Спасибо огромное) просто не в каких гайдах это не указывалось

Comment: Сработало? Если да, поставьте галочку на моем ответе, чтобы принять

Comment: Да ____________

Comment: Тогда, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку на ответе, и если у вас есть стрелочки вверх на моем вопросе и комментариях, поставьте их, (это типа лайка). А то мне не хватает немного очков опыта для нового достижения

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле не тупой, потому что анимации не так уж и просты